# How to capture Histogram Oriented Gradients in the visualisation figure?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection, pattern-recognition

Firstly, many apologies if this question has been posted/asked/answered (let me know the link if that is the case).
How do I capture the HOG values displayed/plotted on the visualisation figure in Matlab?For example in this link (Matlab) https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extracthogfeatures.html

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
[featureVector,hogVisualization] = extractHOGFeatures(img);

%Plot HOG features on the original image    
figure;
imshow(img);
hold on;
plot(hogVisualization);
```

What I don't understand is when I open '`hogVisualization`' in matlab the values which are plotted in the image don't make sense. Where can I find the values plotted on the original image?

To be more specific, here is what I'm trying to do. In this image here > [phase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjeaZ.png) I'm trying to detect the lines in the red region (I can detect these lines). However, as you can see these lines are disconnected in the blue region. In my algorithm, I need to track which direction I should go (e.g. to the left, right or to a certain angle direction) when it reaches the disconnected line.

For this purpose, I used HOG to find the orientation. Visually, I can see the correct orientation when I visualise it, which can be used to connect two disconnected lines within the blue region. But the problem is I need to find the values plotted in the image. How do I get these values? I can see them visualised on the image but I can't retrieve the actual numerical values.

Thanks,
Erick

Comment: I don't know if this will help but I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240596/undefined-function-extracthogfeatures-for-input-arguments-of-type-uint8)

Comment: Thanks Hojo..but it is not the problem of Matlab. It's just I don't know how to capture the directional values visualised on the image using 'hogVisualisation'. When I use 'plot(hogVisualation)', it displays all directional/orientations in every block but I don't know where to find these values.

Comment: the values are stored in the `featureVector`. A good place to start would be the [`documentation`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/extracthogfeatures.html#outputarg_features). In your code this is a `9x62x62` matrix, not sure about the order of the dimensions. 9 is the number of orientations.

Comment: Hi @Vahe Tshitoyan, my understanding is that the `featureVector` contains the occurrences of orientation. It doesn't tell whether the orientation is 120, 45, 89 degrees, etc. What confuses me even more is if I delete `featureVector`  and use `plot(hogVisualization)` I still can plot the orientations on the image.

Comment: @ErickYA maybe you are interested in [ingredient](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgradient.html) instead